# How to format full width unicode string correctly

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-unicode, unicode-string

It seems that python add only one half width space to format the string, but for full width characters, there should be a full width space or two half width space. Is there any solution?

the code is :

```
template = "{:3s}测试"
print(template.format("测试"))
print(template.format("测试二"))
```

then the output:

```
测试 测试
测试二测试
```

when I change `3` to `4` , the output is:

```
测试  测试
测试二 测试
```

but the output I want is

```
测试  测试
测试二测试
```

Answer (score 0):

See [python docs format-examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) , the 6th example shows that we can use `{:*^30}` to make text center and filled with `*` ( `^` means center and the char in front of it is the fill char). Just use full width space 　 to replace `*` in this example.

So finally, my template string is:

`{:　>3s}测试`

`>` means right align. See [python docs format-specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for all align chars

the output is:

```
　测试测试
测试二测试
```

I also tried to use two half-width space as the fill char, but it raised `ValueError: Invalid format specifier` .

Hope the answer will help someone in the future